# insertAfter, then remove previous element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Getting some weird behavior with a piece of code that's supposed to do simple DOM manipulation:

```
b.detach();
b.insertAfter(a);
a.remove();
```

Initially the HTML looks like

```
<a>
  <b> </b>
</a>
```

(if it matters, I'm using `b.wrap('<a></a>')` to build it)

After that code runs it's supposed to move `b` after `a`:

```
<a></a>
<b></b>
```

then remove `a`:

```
<b></b>
```

but it doesn't. Instead `a` remains there and `b` just disappears. Any ideas on what could be wrong?

I tried using `after()` instead, reversing arguments, but getting the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean, if I try it, it works the way you want it:

http://jsfiddle.net/8wy7v/

HTML:

```
<div id="test">
    <a>
        Test <b>Test</b>
    </a>
</div>

<button id="change_dom">manipulate</button>
<br />
<textarea id="result"></textarea>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#change_dom').click(function(){
        var a = $('a'),
            b = $('b');

        b.detach();
        b.insertAfter(a);
        a.remove();

        $('#result').val($('#test').html());
    });
});
```

**Update:**

This is how it can be done in the scenario described in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8wy7v/1/

```
var list = b.parents('ul')
b.insertAfter(list);
list.remove();
```

Comment: Hi that's weird:) I've updated your fiddle to reflect my actual code- http://jsfiddle.net/8wy7v/1/ and it has the same issue

Comment: That strange indeed. It seems that as soon as you call 'wrap', the variable `a` doesn't contain the `ul` and `li` elements anymore. I'll update my answer with how you can solve it, but I don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: ok so wrap() was the issue :/ thanks! i replaced wrap() with a combination of insertAfter and append, that worked too

Answer (score 1):

remove b.detach() 
b.insertAfter(a); will move it

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that `wrap` does clone the elements - so what is referenced by `a` never actually contains `b`. Btw, the `detach` is superfluous, as elements will be automatically removed when inserted elsewhere in the DOM.

So to get the `a` after which to insert, you will need to reselect it (e.g. by `b.parent()`).

Comment: thanks, good to know. I thought that wrap() would be a shortcut to  `a.insertAfter(b); a.find('li').append(b);` :)